# How do I install Chrome shortcut app via the command line?

Tags: google-chrome, shortcuts, dotfiles

As a Ubuntu user who has his own dotfiles I would like to install windowed Chrome (shortcut) apps via my dotfiles. So if I do a fresh install I also have setup my Chrome shortcut apps (like outlook).

Normally i would create a Chrome shortcut like this:

1. Open Chrome
2. Click three dots vertically aligned (top right)
3. Click more tools
4. Create shortcut
5. Keep name and check open as window
6. Click create

But how to create shortcut via zsh command line? (without going through the UI). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to install a shortcut to let chrome to run it as a shortcut.
With this piece of code you can run any website as a app:

`google-chrome --app=https://listen.tidal.com`

This will run Tidal as a app.
For more info see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/741591/launch-a-chrome-app-from-command-line